# random.nextInt() gives me cannot find symbol

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn java. When i'm running the code in DrJava i get this message: cannot find symbol. I tried several things but nothing works. When i'm searching the internet I get most of the times the problem is 'import java.util.Random;', but I wrote that down. Anyone knows what the problem is? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class dobbelsteen {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        int dobb1;
        int dobb2;
        int dobb3;
        int dobb4;
        int dobb5;

        boolean alldobb = true;

        do {
            dobb1 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dobb2 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dobb3 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dobb4 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            dobb5 = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
            if (dobb1 != dobb2 && dobb2 != dobb3 && dobb3 != dobb4 && dobb4 != dobb5) { 
                System.out.println(dobb1 + dobb2 + dobb3 + dobb4 + dobb5); 
           }
            else {
                System.out.println(dobb1 + dobb2 + dobb3 + dobb4 + dobb5);
                alldobb = false;
            }
        }while(alldobb);
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't declared random

Comment: Indent your code properly if you want people to try and read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random` is not declared, you need to do it:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Comment: It happens to everyone^^

Comment: @Frank Please mark the answer as correct and upvote it, if you're happy with the solution. This will reward the people that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a instance of the class random so that you can use the object and it´s method.

```
Random random = new Random();
random.nextRandom(X,Y);
```

---

You just can call `Class.method()` when the method is declared as `static` - so there is no need to initalize it.